# Simplify $\frac{b} { \frac{1}{w} + \frac{1}{w^{3/2}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify $\displaystyle\frac{b} {  \frac{1}{w}  +  \frac{1}{w^{3/2}}}$

Very confused on how to do this. The simplified answer should be $\displaystyle\frac{bw^{3/2}}{1 + w^{1/2}}$ but I am not sure why. Please help.

Comment: What are $b,w,x$?

Comment: What is $\;b\;$ , what is $\;w\;$ ? Where are the operations being done?

Comment: I heavily edited your post. please be sure I did not make any mistakes.

Comment: I suspect $b$ should actually be $x$. Try multiplying $\frac{b}{\frac{1}{w}+\frac{1}{w^{3/2}}}$ by $1 = \frac{w^{3/2}}{w^{3/2}}$ to see what happens.

Comment: No b should just stand for any integer

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{b}{\frac{1}{w}+\frac{1}{w^{3/2}}}&=\frac{b}{\frac{w^{1/2}+1}{w^{3/2}}}\\
&=b\div\frac{w^{1/2}+1}{w^{3/2}}\\
&=b\times\frac{w^{3/2}}{w^{1/2}+1}\\
&=\frac{bw^{3/2}}{w^{1/2}+1}
\end{align}$$

---

**NOTE**: As @Troy indicated, I also suspect that $b$ should $x$ (or indeed $x$ should be $b$) in your question for it to make sense

Comment: How are you transitioning from the first expression to the next? I don't understand how algebraically how the denominators are equal.

Comment: NOTE: $w^{3/2}=w.w^{1/2}$. Therefore:$$\frac{1}{w}=\frac{1}{w}\times\frac{w^{1/2}}{w^{1/2}}=\frac{w^{1/2}}{w^{3/2}}$$This is used to get the common denominator of $w^{3/2}$ in the fraction sum in the denominator.

Comment: I should have payed attention in algebra class :/ Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\frac{b}{\frac{1}{w}  +  \frac{1}{w^{3/2}}}$

Multiply both the numerator and denominator by $w^{3/2}$
\begin{align*}
\implies &\frac{bw^{3/2}}{\frac{w^{3/2}}{w} + 1}
\end{align*}
And from the law of indices, we have that: $$\frac{w^{3/2}}{w} = w^{\frac{3}{2} - 1} = w^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

\begin{align*}
\implies &\frac{bw^{3/2}}{w^{1/2} + 1}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Write $w^{1/2}=\sqrt{w}=z$, to simplify things; your expression becomes
$$
E=\frac{b}{\dfrac{1}{w}+\dfrac{1}{w^{3/2}}}=
\frac{b}{\dfrac{1}{z^2}+\dfrac{1}{z^3}}
$$
Treat first the denominator:
$$
\dfrac{1}{z^2}+\dfrac{1}{z^3}=\frac{z+1}{z^3}
$$
so
$$
E=b\frac{z^3}{z+1}=\frac{bz^3}{z+1}=\frac{bw^{3/2}}{w^{1/2}+1}
$$